# Can you distribute compute work over multiple frames (Vulkan)?

Tags: c++, graphics, gpgpu, vulkan, compute-shader

Assume you have a very simple rendering system, with a single rendering pass and a single compute pass. Say the render pass takes 12 ms in any given frame and the compute pass takes 6 ms. Thus their total combined time is more than 16 ms.

Say, however, that you don't need your compute work to be done in one frame, and you can do it in 2, but that it cannot be split between 2 dispatches, i.e. you have to call it all at once.

Can you indicate to the driver that it should prioritize the graphics rendering and that it can distribute the compute work over 2 frames?

Comment: "*but that it cannot be split between 2 dispatches*" I'm curious as to how exactly that would be possible. If you're firing off more than a single workgroup, then you *can* launch multiple dispatch calls.

Comment: Sounds like something for asynchronous compute: have 2 queues when creating device, one graphics - one compute, and it also lets you give queues priorities iirc.

Comment: The synchronisation could be done with events or semaphores